# Adding TCP Socket connections to Chrome Extension via Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After an exhaustive search, I've come to the understanding that there's no direct way to implement TCP Socket connections in a Google Chrome Extension.

So, I've decided to embed a Flash file into the Extension and then use Flash to initiate the Socket connection while using JS to exchange information between the Flash file and the webpage.

<strike>I've not tested this practically, yet, but</strike> would this be an efficient way to go about?

[Note : Embedding Flash works like a charm in Extensions. :)]

[P.S. : Embedding Flash to use Socket Connections worked like a charm too. :)]

Comment: Have you considered websockets?

Comment: Levi, websockets are not really appropriate for my case. :)